# How to import modules from a file as root

Tags: python

I am trying to import a module from an external file as follows:

```
>>> from sys import path
>>> path.append("/tmp/security/")
>>> from util import set_archive
```

When I run this as root it works fine. But when I run this as `testuser` it does not work.

permissions on /tmp/security/util.py is as follows:

```
[root@dashmpp-head-0 - Db2wh /]# ls -l /tmp/security/util.py
-rwx------ 1 db2inst1 root 88046 Dec  4 19:08 /tmp/security/util.py
```

when I try to import as testuser I get:

```
>>> from sys import path
>>> path.append("/tmp/security/")
>>> from util import set_archive
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'
>>>
```

testuser belongs to another groups called `db2iadm1`

Is there any way I can import the module as root so I can use `set_archive` function?

Comment: Run python as root, or as a user in group `db2iadm1`. Python's module I/O and file I/O inherit the permissions of whoever ran the program

Comment: I cannot. The program has to executed as user testuser.

Comment: Depending on what the file is and how secure the information in it is, you might set its permissions to `744`, which allows everyone to read it. The current setting (`700`) is unusual and generally only used for things that have private keys or other secure information in them (like ssh keys) and not usually used for source code.

Comment: 744 did not work. I can see PYNOPATH has `/tmp/security/` in the list.

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 db2inst1 root 88046 Dec  4 19:08 /tmp/security/util.py
```

In fact 777 also did not work which is strange.

Comment: `drwx------  1 dsadm    db2iadm1 4096 Dec  4 21:06 security` I think its because of the parent directory permissions/ownership.